# WSL2 Remote Desktop Can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons

Tags: 20.04, remote-desktop, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xrdp

I am trying to use a GUI with WSL2. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IL7Jd9rjgrM) and it initially worked fine. After rebooting my laptop I opened Ubuntu terminal and typed:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start
```

to start xrdp on the "remote" machine. Then I checked the status:

```
service xrdp status

* xrdp-sesman is running
* xrdp in running
```

So when I go to Windows remote desktop and connect to `localhost:3390`, I get this error:

```
1) Remote access to the server is not enables
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network
```

Within the Ubuntu terminal I check `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` and it shows `port=3390` so I know I'm pointing at the correct port. Since the ubuntu terminal is active, I'm assuming that the remote computer is on, so I don't know what's going on. I followed the manual work around [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5719) but that didn't help.

Comment: Community Bot bumped this today since there's no accepted answer.  Did you get this resolved?  If the information I provided in my answer didn't help, would you write up what solved it for you in a self-accepted answer so that we can "close this out" and it won't get bumped again?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In WSL2, the instance is running in a Hyper-V VM with a virtual NIC that is NAT'd behind the Windows host. However, the Windows host itself *should* have direct access to services running in the instance through `localhost`. WSL appears to do some automatic port-forwarding, but only from the local Windows host to the WSL instance.  This will *not* work from other machines on the network (even other virtual machines on the same Windows host).  But at least you are just using `localhost` for now.

That said, this auto-magic localhost port-forwarding sometimes stops working, *even (and sometimes especially) across reboots.*  This is most often due to hibernation or Windows Fast Startup (also a form of hibernation).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455770/11810933) on Stack Overflow for some more information.

Given that you had it working initially, and then it stopped after a reboot, I'd be hopeful that this is what you are seeing.

So to start with, try exiting out of any WSL instances, then run:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

And then start the instance and try RDP again.

If that works, check to see if Fast Startup is enabled, and disable it if so.  And avoid hibernation.  Or `wsl --shutdown` after hibernating or powering down/up, at least.

If it doesn't work, then we need to look more closely at the actual `xrdp` service to  see what's going on.

Comment: This happened to me.  I believe it was because I started up WSL too quickly while windows started up services.  Following these instructions and restarting WSL, I am now able to connect.